# Update a python dictionary with values from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am using python for the first time and may be doing a silly mistake here.
Need to update values of a dictionary from the results of a sql query in a data frame. Any help on this is appreciated.

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvP2g.jpg) 
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gk96.jpg)

```
import xlwings as xw
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
print("Libraries imported")

print()
print()
print("Creating list of measures to load.")

ListOfVariables = ['RegDrv_Sex','Quote_NCD'] 


print()
print()
print("Creating default dictionaries to load.")


RegDrv_Age  = {'16':0,'17 To 20':0,'21 To 24':0,'25 To 29':0,'30 To 
34':0,'35 To 39':0,'40 To 44':0,'45 To 49':0,'50 To 54':0,'55 To 59':0,'60 
To 64':0,'65 To 69':0,'70 To 74':0,'75 To 79':0,'Over 79':0}
Quote_NCD    = {'0':0,'1':0,'2':0,'3':0,'4':0,'5':0,'6':0,'7':0,'8':0,'9':0}

ListofDictionaries = [RegDrv_Sex,Quote_NCD]

Server = "odsprd"
DataBase = "Staging"

#connection propertry
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=' + Server + ';'
                                'Database=' + DataBase + ';'
                                'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
print()
print()
print("Connected To " + DataBase)
cursor = connection.cursor()

wb = xw.Book(r'C:\PythonApplication1\Overall.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
print()
print()
print("Excel Template Imported.....")

#Source Data
df = sqlquery = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT Variable,Value,AquoteVolume FROM [staging].dbo.aggmitest WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY Variable,Value", connection)

print()
print()
print("Source Data Frame Loaded....")

row=0
for variable in ListOfVariables:
    print()
    print()
    print(variable + " dictionary loaded....")

# update dictonary with values

    df_foreach_variable = df.loc[df.Variable == variable]
    #print(df_foreach_variable)
    df_select = df_foreach_variable.loc[:,['AquoteVolume']] 
    #print(df_select)

    for Dictionary in ListofDictionaries :    
        for item in Dictionary:
            if item in df_select:
                Dictionary.update({item:df_select[item]})
    print()
    print()
    print(Dictionary)   

# Print to Excel     
row = 0 
print()
print()
print("Printing Excel....")
for Dictionary in ListofDictionaries : 
        row+=3
        for i in Dictionary:        
            Cell='B'+str(row)
            wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range(Cell).value = Dictionary[i] 

            row+=1 



print()
print()
print("Excel Print Complete!")
wb.save(r'C:PythonApplication1\Overall2.xlsx')
```

Expected result: Dictionary value should get updated by the values from DF
Actual Result : Dictionaries just showing the defaults.

Results of SQLquery into dataframe for RegDrv_Age:

```
Value      AquoteVolume
16  69
17 To 20    96662
21 To 24    137143
25 To 29    156386
30 To 34    126831
35 To 39    103091
40 To 44    81725
45 To 49    77763
50 To 54    69705
55 To 59    52046
60 To 64    35648
65 To 69    25095
70 To 74    19887
75 To 79    11156
Over 79     6793
```

Comment: Could you provide an input output example ? What you are trying to achieve is not very clear. Do you want to fill your dictionnaries with a count of each uniques values of the dataframe's columns ? do you want to keep the values that do not appear in your dataframe ? add the values that are not present in your defaults dictionnaries ?

Comment: Could you paste output of `print(df_select.head())`

Comment: @LilianBordeau Yes want to fill my dictionaries with the count of each unique values which were already aggregated on SQL and if any categoery is missing from SQL results the defaults in the dictionary for that category ensures that it puts a default.

Comment: @Mohsinhasan print(df_select.head()) is printing nothing mate.

Comment: Results of a dataframe updated in the original post.

Comment: Why is `Variable` column not present in your dataframe?

Comment: @Mohsinhasan The values of the variable column are already in the loaded template. All I need is paste values from the query against it.

Comment: @LilianBordeau Added Input and output to the original post.